# Selenium test error on FirefoxDriver creation

Tags: java, maven, selenium

I'm trying to run selenium tests on server.

But all of them fails with the same error: of org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver

```
 org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host localhost on port 7055 after 45000 ms
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:96)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:148)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:86)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:127)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:82)
```

this happends when i'm trying to create FirefoxDriver

like this

```
 public Driver ()
{
    profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    ff_driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
    ff_driver.manage().window().maximize();
}
```

Comment: Have you the `selenium-firefox-driver.jar` in your classpath?

Comment: Yes i do , the problem is that it's runing on my local through Eclipse , but when i'm testing it on Jenkins with maven i get this .

Comment: Look [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5333) maybe this can help you.

Comment: did you try putting firefox in your path variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to use an newest version of Selenium webdriver.

You can try with 2.33 or if it's doesn't work try with 2.42.0.

If you use maven, you can edit your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.33.0</version> // or 2.42.0
</dependency>
```

IF you are not using maven, you can download the latest version here

*[Selenium Client & WebDriver Language Bindings]*

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/

Answer (score 0):

maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.0rc3</version>
</dependency>
```

install and put in your server.

I hope it helps.